# How to resolve Oracle service name to ip address it resides

Tags: .net, oracle

I have OracleConnectionString with connection info.  All I see now is to start tnsping as a hidden process and parse its output.  Is there a simpler (.NET) way?

Comment: I think you already use the best way. Don't forget that a service can run on nodeA now and on nodeB in the next moment.... Don't make yourself dependent from this kind of info.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sys_context('USERENV','ip_address') from dual;
```

I am not sure of this!  Please, try!